# Function SUM is not working as expected in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I have 2 tables

```
table_orders - order_id, customer_id;
table_order_details - order_id, product_sell_price, quantity;
```

I want to get the order-value(sum of amount) for each of the orders. I am trying this query:

```
mysql> select O.order_id, sum(OD.product_sell_price * OD.quantity) from table_order_details as OD INNER JOIN table_orders as O where O.order_id = TOD.order_id;
```

But it is giving overall sum i.e. sum for all the orders.

How to get the  order-value for each order?

Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Add at the end a GROUP BY

```
SELECT O.order_id, SUM(OD.product_sell_price * OD.quantity) 
FROM table_order_details as OD 
INNER JOIN table_orders as O 
ON O.order_id = OD.order_id
 GROUP BY  O.order_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use **GROUP BY** clause to fetch orderwise **SUM**

Try this:

```
SELECT O.order_id, SUM(OD.product_sell_price * OD.quantity) 
FROM table_order_details AS OD 
INNER JOIN table_orders AS O WHERE O.order_id = OD.order_id
GROUP BY O.order_id;
```